# Difference in iOS browser

Tags: html, ios, css, browser, font-size

When visualising this website (http://bluecodestudio.com/kipos/updates/new/) on my desktop's browser and on my iPhone's browser, there is an annoying difference which I can't fix.

The 'p' tags, which have a lower font-size, are displayed with the same font-size as the 'h2' tags when viewed on iOS' Safari.

Which is the reason? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile Safari and some other mobile browsers often increase text size to make it more readable.

You can disable this in CSS with the rule:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
```

There are also -moz and -ms prefixes for other mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid differences between the Browser specific default stylesheets use something like Eric's [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or (what i prefer) [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/)
Continue reading here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset

Comment: Thanks for this resets! It seems like I was using a simple one that didn't take into account mobile devices..

Answer (score 1):

It is because they are using different stylesheets, one for the mobile device, one for the desktop. On the iPhone, h2 is 23 px and p is 22 px, and you are not seeing much difference. On the desktop, h2 is 20 px and p is 14 px, which is a big difference and is readily visible.

You can readily discover this sort of thing with a really cool but little known Mobile Safari feature, Web Inspector, which allows you to see the CSS and other details of a Web page showing on your iPhone by connecting it to your desktop computer and reading those details with desktop Safari. Wow.